# Second Derivative of polar function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polar-coordinates

i'm trying to find $ \frac{d^2\rho}{(d\phi)^2}$ of $\rho=\tan(\phi+\rho)$
in this exercise is not specified if $\rho$ (argument of tangent) is a constant o another variable.

I do $$\rho'=\sec^2(\phi+\rho) $$
then i re-derivate it  $$ \rho''=2 \sec^2(\phi+\rho)\tan(\phi+\rho) $$

In my answer book this must be: $$ −\frac{\cot^3(\phi+\rho)}{\sin(\phi+\rho)}$$

Obviously i make a mistake or a misinterpreted some concept. I need some orientation or a example in order to continue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't use the same letter $\rho$ for two different quantities. Please, clarify your notation

Comment: that is why i'm confused, they used the same expression for a 2 different things, so if we asume that $\rho$ inside of the tangent argument is $\theta$...

Comment: It could be a typo. Do you have any way to check? Assuming it's a constant, your derivative seems correct to me

Comment: Unfortunately no, i have only that answer in my book and i don't recive any feedback from my professor yet. So thecnically i go to the constant-side of the interpretation but what if $\theta$ is a variable too, there is a rule to make a kind of implicit derivative of polar function?

Comment: In this case, there's nothing special about it being a polar function. If it's indeed just a second derivative you are searching for and not anything more complicated, then it doesn't matter if you replace $\phi$ by $x$

Comment: So is it an implicit function?  I.e., $\tan(\phi + \rho) - \rho = 0$?

Comment: In fact I didn't treat it as an implicit function until now. But i will try it.

Answer (score 1):

Well considering $ 0=\tan(\phi+\rho)-\rho $ as a implicit function
I proceed to derivate respect to $\phi$
$$ 0=\tan(\phi+\rho)-\rho$$
$$ 0=\sec^2(\phi+\rho)((1+\rho')-\rho'$$
$$ 0=\sec^2(\phi+\rho)+sec^2(\phi+\rho)\rho'-\rho'$$
$$ -\sec^2(\phi+\rho)=\rho'(sec^2(\phi+\rho)-1)$$
$$ \rho'=\frac{-\sec^2(\phi+\rho)}{(sec^2(\phi+\rho)-1)}$$
then I go to the second derivative of $\phi$

$$\rho''=\frac{-(2\sec^2(\phi+\rho)\tan((\phi+\rho))(1+\rho')(\sec^2(\phi+\rho)-1)+(2\sec^2(\phi+\rho)\sec^2(\phi+\rho)\tan(\phi+\rho)(1+\rho')}{(\sec^2(\phi+\rho)-1)^2}$$
$$\rho''=\frac{(1+\rho')[-2\sec^2(\phi+\rho)\tan((\phi+\rho))(\sec^2(\phi+\rho)-1)+(2\sec^4(\phi+\rho)\tan(\phi+\rho]}{(\sec^2(\phi+\rho)-1)^2}   $$

$$ \rho''=\frac{(1+\rho')\biggl(-2\sec^2(\phi+\rho)\tan((\phi+\rho))\biggl[(\sec^2(\phi+\rho)-1)+(\sec^2(\phi+\rho)\biggr]\biggr)}{(\sec^2(\phi+\rho)-1)^2} $$

$$ \rho''=\frac{(1+\rho')\biggl(-4\sec^2(\phi+\rho)\tan((\phi+\rho))\biggr)}{(\sec^2(\phi+\rho)-1)} $$
now replacing $\rho'$ in $\rho''$
$$ \rho''=\frac{(1+\frac{-\sec^2(\phi+\rho)}{(sec^2(\phi+\rho)-1)})\biggl(-4\sec^2(\phi+\rho)\tan((\phi+\rho))\biggr)}{(\sec^2(\phi+\rho)-1)} $$

$$ \rho''=\frac{(\frac{-1}{(sec^2(\phi+\rho)-1)})\biggl(-4\sec^2(\phi+\rho)\tan((\phi+\rho))\biggr)}{(\sec^2(\phi+\rho)-1)} $$
Finally
$$ \rho''=\frac{\biggl(4\sec^2(\phi+\rho)\tan((\phi+\rho))\biggr)}{(\sec^2(\phi+\rho)-1)^2} $$

this is more tricky than considering the $\rho$ inside of the argument of tangent like a constant, but still not looking like my suppousted answer. Sorry for the long equation but i want to show every step, so if someone find some error or if i miss something somewere please comment.

Comment: Your life will be much easier if you stop using $\sec$ and explicitly write $1/\cos$ instead. Maybe it's just me. For example, your first derivative will simply become $-1/\sin^2 (\phi+\rho)$